# Laravel Mix js combining all js files

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

How do I combine all of my js files to a single file with laravel mix? and is it a good practice to directly keep the downloaded external plugins js files and CSS files in public directory? because we have a js folder already in resource folder and it's getting compiled and saved in public directory when we do `npm run production`, not sure if this is correct or not.

This is how my resource folder looks like :

[image]

And my app.js file looks like this :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include those libraries by installing them to NPM with `npm install jquery` for instance.  Then in your `bootstrap.js` file you would have something like:

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery');
```

That would make it available in the window, and then you still have just one js file to include on the client (your compiled `app.js` file).

If you do have a file you want separate from your main bundle, and it isn't one you have pulled in through NPM, it's not a bad thing to commit it straight to the public folder. I would keep them in `/resources/assets/js/vendor` and then use `mix.copy` to move them into `/public/js/vendor`. Thats just because I prefer all of my work to be in `resources` and to have `public` be all compiled or copied files.

Answer (score 1):

you can add them from npm , or if these are external plugins like my case you can do this

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
 .scripts([
          "path/plugin1.js",
          "path/plugin2.js",
           .......
         ], 'public/js/all.js').styles([
          "path/plugin1.css",
          "path/plugin2.css",
          .....
         ],'public/css/all.css');
```

for more useful information you can visit : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix

Comment: so it's like the plugin1.js and plugin2.js will get combined together and will get saved in public/js folder as all.js? and one more thing if I install a package via npm where does it reside I mean the location ?

Comment: in your node_modules folder

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm to install jquery  and do it like this same with jeff

```
window.$ = require('jquery');
```

OR but if you have your own script want to include then

just put it top on vue instance

```
require('./jquery.js') //based on your picture it jquery and app.js are in same level 


window.vue = require('Vue')
```

this will automatically read and being compiled by the npm.